# Calling amqp message queque is not asynchronous

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rabbitmq, amqp

Here is my code:

```
class ParsepdfClient 
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

require 'amqp'
require "rubygems"
require 'mq'

  def self.test

    EventMachine.run do
        connection = AMQP.connect(:host => '127.0.0.1')
        puts "Connected to AMQP broker. Running #{AMQP::VERSION} version of the gem..."

        channel = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
        queue = channel.queue("amqpgem.examples.helloworld", :auto_delete => true)
        exchange = channel.direct("")

        queue.subscribe do |payload|
            sleep(1.minutes)
            puts "Received a message: #{payload}. Disconnecting..."
            connection.close { EventMachine.stop }
        end

        exchange.publish "Hello, world!", :routing_key => queue.name
    end   
  end
end
```

I'm using [Rabbitmq](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) as a broker with rails [amqp gem](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/amqp/).  Now I'm calling :

`ParsepdfClient.test` from a controller.

From my understanding my call shouldn't sleep for a minute but it waits for a minute and it outputs

```
"Received a message: Hello, world!. Disconnecting..."
```

And then it executes rest of my code of controller. Shouldn't  the call  be asynchronous? 
If not how can I make it asynchronous?

What I mean is that shouldn't it execute the rest of the code of my controller after outputting

```
Connected to AMQP broker. Running #{AMQP::VERSION} version of the gem...
```

Comment: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/192999 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975140/reliable-timing-with-eventmachine-periodic-timers might help.

Comment: I have an impression that all asynchronous code should be within `EventMachine.run` block.

Comment: @VictorMoroz It is :)

Comment: What's wrong then? `EventMachine.run` will terminate after the call `EventMachine.stop`, i.e. after 1 minute as expected.

Comment: check https://github.com/gocardless/hutch

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement  Rabbitmq in rails successfully with the help of my senior. If any one is having any issue I have written a blog post [here](http://sachin-prasad.blogspot.in/2013/08/rabbitmq-implementation-in-rails-using.html).